# Data not togglling in reactAppexcharts pie chart

Tags: reactjs, legend, pie-chart

I am using react-apexcharts to create a pie chart I want to toggle the data based on lagend click.
My Pie chart code:

```
  const PieChart = {
    series: [r1, b1, m1, s1],//They are my counts.
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        events: {
          legendClick: function (chartContext, seriesIndex, config) {
            toggleDataSeries(seriesIndex);
          },
          dataPointSelection: function (event, chartContext, config) {
            openDataTable(config.dataPointIndex);
          },
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'right',
        horizontalAlign: 'right',
        offsetY: 30,
        onItemClick: {
          toggleDataSeries: true,
        },
      },
      labels: ['R1', 'B1', 'M1', 'S1'],
      colors: ['#FF0000', '#FFCC00', '#0000CC', '#97c200', '#660099', '#00FF00', '#FF6600', '#003300', '#00FFFF', '#800000'],
      title: {
        text: 'Attacks',
        align: 'center',
        style: {
          fontSize: '18px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: '#333',
          floating: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };


  const toggleDataSeries = (seriesIndex) => {
  alert("toggleDataSeries  : "+seriesIndex);
    const updatedSeries = [...PieChart.series];
    updatedSeries[seriesIndex].visible = !updatedSeries[seriesIndex].visible;
    PieChart.series = updatedSeries;
  };
```

I am getting seriesIndex properly.
but
I getting an Uncaught runtime error:
ERROR:
can't assign to property "visible" on 7: not an object

the 7 is my count for that seriesIndex